# Reading uploaded file as string array

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm uploading a file which is a multi line text document.  I need to extract certain lines out of the document and then store in database as a byte array.
I've been able to create a string which shows all the line break characters but unsure how to create a string array so i can edit line by line.

```
  public async Task<string> Upload()
    {
        // get Id of GSM
        string id = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["id"];
        // get Current logged in user
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        var test = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // extract file name and file contents
        var fileNameParam = provider.Contents[0].Headers.ContentDisposition.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToLower() == "filename");
        string fileName = (fileNameParam == null) ? "" : fileNameParam.Value.Trim('"');

        //read as byte array
        byte[] file = await provider.Contents[0].ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        // read as string
        string text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(file);

       // Convert to string array???

        var result = string.Format("Received '{0}' with length: {1}", fileName, file.Length);
        return text;

    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for this: `text.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' });`?

Comment: I have \r\n at the end of each line, using this creates an array double in size with a blank element ("") between each line

Answer (score 0):

This will read the text file line by line from the uploaded file and than write the lines you want to keep to a stream writer with an underlying memory stream, Than just call `.ToArray()` to get the byte array you need to store in the database.
`SomeCondition` in the code would determine which lines to keep.

```
byte[] byteArray;
using (var targetStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(targetStream))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(await provider.Contents[0].ReadAsStreamAsync()))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        if(SomeCondition)
           writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
    byteArray = targetStream.ToArray();
}
```